# NVidia Nsight Debugger - Geometry window doesn't work

Tags: debugging, graphics, directx-11, nsight

I programmed an application that displays a quad, which works perfectly.
However, if I try to debug my application with NVidia's Nsight debugger, the quad is not shown in the Geometry window.
Even if I switch to the memory tab, the submitted vertices in the vertex and index buffers are not visible.
The strange thing though is, that if I watch the buffers in the resource window, they are shown correctly.

This is a image of the application when it is running:
[image: Running application]

This is an image of the resource view (vertex buffer and index buffer):
[image: Vertex Buffer resource view]
[image: Index Buffer resource view]

Here are the geometry window tabs:
[image: Geometry memory window]
[image: Geometry graphical view]

I am using DirectX 11 with Visual Studio 2015, if that's important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for NSight to fail to display the geometry...

On initialization of the Input Assembler (IA) stage I used the `D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT` macro when initializing the `D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC` structure. If I set those values manually, NSight displays the geometry correctly.

I still don't know why that's the case. Is it intended by NVidia or is it just a bug?